# Stream async Read/Write freezing UI thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, filestream, networkstream

I am having issues with the async `Read()` and `Write()` methods on `FileStream/NetworkStream`.

In my program I am sending a file to a server, I don't want the file upload operation to freeze the main thread so I use the `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` functions but something is still freezing the UI thread.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task SendFile(File file)
{
    if (socket == null || !socket.Connected) throw new Exception();

    using (NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket, FileAccess.Write, false))
    using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(file.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; 
        int read = 0;

         while ((read = await fStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
         {
             await networkStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
         }
         await networkStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

The part where I call `SendFile(File file)`:

```
private async void SendForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileSender fileSender = new FileSender();
    Queue<Computer> receiverQueue = new Queue<Computer>(receivers);

    while (receiverQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        Computer recv = receiverQueue.Dequeue();
        await fileSender.Connect(recv);
        bool approved = await fileSender.RequestFileSend(file);
        if (!approved)
        {
            continue;
        }
        await fileSender.SendFile(file);
        await fileSender.Disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the code that calls `SendFile` the problem is likely there, keep showing the calling methods till you get to the entry point event. You likely have a `.Result` or a `.Wait()` somewhere higher up the call stack.

Comment: Maybe `await networkStream.FlushAsync();` is resulting into blocking call?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I added the code where I call `SendFile(File file)`.

Comment: @Zero `SendForm_Shown` looks like an event handler which does allow `async void` so that should not be the cause. What about `Connect`, `RequestFileSend` and the others that belong to `FileSender` Check them to make sure there are no blocking calls.

Comment: @Nkosi the freezing happens when the `SendFile` method is executing.

Comment: @Zero have you stepped through `SendFile` to try to identify where it locks up.

Comment: I would've assumed the same thing as @ScottChamberlain, actually - are you sure that you don't do `Wait()` or `.Result` anywhere?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I know. That is why I also asked the OP to check the other methods apart from you already suggesting checking up the call stack

Comment: @Nkosi I have stepped through SendFile but it is impossible to see where it locks up.

Comment: And it is definitely a problem inside `SendFile()` because I don't have the problem when I wrap that method inside `Task.Run(() => {});`.

I really don't know what the problem is though.